# Static member in two DLL C++

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I have a class with a static member and the definition of the member is in the cpp file.

I have to use the same definition of the member in two different DLL and so i need to include the cpp definition in the two projects for the compilation. This is making a new "version" of the member. Meaning the cpp is compiled at two places and it will have two definitions.

How can I have only one definition in the two DLL.
Or what am I doing wrong or what do I miss?

In the .h

```
class qwerty
{
public:
  static xyz* abc;
};
```

In the .cpp

```
xyz* qwerty::abc = new xyz();
```

And in the two DLL i include the .h where I need and the .cpp is linked in the project.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use shared memory to share data between two modules:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie wouldn't that prevent you from running more than one instance of the program?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to wrap that static member into a static member function that delivers it. As so:

```
class qwerty
{
public:
  static xyz* get_abc();
};
```

in cpp file (only in DLL):

```
xyz* qwerty::get_abc() {
  static xyz inst;
  return &inst;
};
```

This is in good old fashion Meyers' singleton style.

N.B.: I hope I don't have to tell you about the ABI-related dangers of passing around C++ objects or exporting classes through module boundaries, right?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either - the compiler needs to keep track internally whether the variable was initialized, and that tracking will also be duplicated in each DLL.

Comment: But... this can work if the function is placed in a *third* DLL all by itself.

Comment: The third DLL worked! Thanks!
I do have a DLL only for that, but it works.

Comment: @MarkRansom This will work as long as there is only a single definition of the static function in the whole application (exe + DLLs), that's the ODR, after all. But it's true that you might prefer to create a third "helper" DLL to make the dependencies work out (or be more "symmetric", instead of asymmetrically shifting the unique definition to one DLL, making the other DLL dependent on it).